# MySQL - Date Range Query

Tags: mysql

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16501a/1

I have this query which looks for rooms that are not booked within a date range entered by a user:

```
select rooms.*
from rooms
where 
  (
    rooms.id not in (
      select room_id
      from bookings
      inner join statuses on statuses.id = status_id
      where start <= '2018-01-16 11:00:00'
      and end >= '2018-01-15 12:00:00'
      and statuses.name in ('Approved', 'Completed')
    )
  )
;

--  1st Query - No results due to clashes --
```

This works perfectly fine, but I am looking to add an extra bit of logic but I can't seem to get it working.

As part of the room booking process, a checksheet is completed afterwards, and this table has a `keys_returned_at` column, I want to take this column in to account and show the room as available but only if it doesn't clash with existing bookings.

I have tried adding the following to the above:

```
-- this is the new part --
or (
  rooms.id in (
    select room_id
    from bookings
    inner join statuses on statuses.id = status_id
    inner join checksheets on checksheets.booking_id = bookings.id
    where start <= '2018-01-16 11:00:00'
    and end >= '2018-01-15 12:00:00'
    and statuses.name = 'Completed'
    and checksheets.completed = 1
    and checksheets.keys_returned_at <= '2018-01-16 11:00:00'
  )
)
```

which seems to work mostly, but doesn't restrict on any existing bookings that might be in the database, so it returns the room in the results when there's a clash when it shouldn't.

e.g. example bookings might be:

**Rooms**

```
id |        start        |           end       | status_id | room_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 2018-01-15 08:00:00 | 2018-01-16 08:00:00 |     1     |    1
 2 | 2018-01-15 11:00:00 | 2018-01-17 08:00:00 |     1     |    1
```

**Checksheets**

```
id | room_id |  keys_returned_at
----------------------------------
 1 |    1    | 2018-01-15 10:00:00
```

and example search criteria would be `2018-01-15 12:00:00` to `2018-01-16 12:00:00`.

If only booking one was in the database, then room 1 should be returned in the results since it doesn't clash with the search terms since it starts after the `keys_returned_at` timestamp (and the end doesn't clash with any other bookings, just there aren't any other bookings), however, when booking two is involved, no availability should be returned since the search start date is after the `start` date for booking `2`.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your question because it's hard to understand the logic of it. What you are trying to achieve? When the keys are returned, why not just mark the booking as 'Completed'? Why do you need to add a different condition, and how does it relate to the first one?

Comment: Hi @rlanvin, I appreciate that it's hard to understand. The original query excludes rooms where there's already bookings that overlap the supplied date range, I'm just trying to extend it to return rooms when a room is handed back early, so if someone were then to search with a date range between the handed back date and the end date, hopefully that makes more sense?

Comment: Can't you simply cancel the booking (or change the booking end date) in that situation?

Comment: I've thought about it, but not sure if I want to do that, by not doing it, it preserves the two dates and means it's possible to look back and see if people are booking things for too long etc.

Comment: In this case why not have another set of date in bookings? For example "checkin" and "checkout" (both nullable)? This way you can compare the "start" and "stop" booked with the actual "checkin" and "checkout" time. In addition add a flag to the rooms table which says "occupied" yes/no, and update this flag when the keys are returned. It would make your queries much, much easier (not to mention faster). I realize this does not directly answer you question, it's simply a comment.

Comment: thanks, I will have a wee think about it

Comment: I might have found a solution, just trying to ensure it's not going to result in any double bookings - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/770e74/36

Comment: I don't want to be mean or anything, but this looks overly complicated. I think you need to update the first "not in", not add another one, especially not as a union. You want the room that are *not in* the list of rooms that are booked *but not in* your "checksheets" table. Something like this anyway. Hope this helps.